Need Recommendations for Easy Website Development with these Specific CMS Cases
I've hit a crossroads. My current skills are limited to HTML, CSS, and a bit of JavaScript. I want to build a website visually, and if coding is necessary, I prefer to keep it minimal using the languages I mentioned, or if I must learn more languages must be minimal coding or learning on my part. Could you please recommend me FREE websites or technologies that can help me achieve the following use cases?
About Frontend I prefer to do it with above technologies or preferably using a website builder if there's any. Specific example:
I want to create a listing page of articles on frontend. When an article is clicked to go to the article page which contains YouTube and Facebook embeds.
About CMS I must easily manage database, to add and retrieve data efficiently. Specific examples that I want to accomplish from CMS:

I need to organize recipes into lists: breakfast, lunch, and dinner.
I’d like to be able to add a same recipe to these multiple lists and
finally display these lists on the frontend.

I want to be able to generate and update a json file, and then to use
json at frontend (at frontend reading json can be done with
javascript no problem, but what about CMS: how to generate json, what
technologies?).

I want to upload recipes from backend (admin dashboard), with ability
to use 3rd party API to send audio files there.


Of course I know that hosting and domain name are NOT free. But I just need free technologies to accomplish the above.
Please read my cases carefully and thank you very much for your recommendations.

You might want to take a look at http://cmsmatrix.org/

@Mawg are you sure??? the website says: This domain name may be for sale

Oh, no, that used to be a great site. Check for it on archive,org  It has a wizard which asks you questions and recommends a CMS. Sorry, I just commented from memory, as I have not used it for a while

Without learning any coding, the answer in 99.99% of cases is WordPress + plugins if necessary. I don't quite understand your requirements 2 and 3, the JSON one is poorly described especially, so can't propose good set of plugins
